# Configure apache to use domain folders

Tags: apache

I need to create a configuration for apache - to point every domain to a folder named after it. For example:

```
website.com -> /var/www/website.com/www/
www.website.com -> /var/www/website.com/www/
subdomain.website.com -> /var/www/subdomain.website.com/www/
```

www needs to be linked to the same folder as a base domain.
Tell me please, what configuration do I need?
Thanks!

Update:

I need to be able to add new websites without changing apache configuration, just create a new folder and it will work. So configuration must be like  a wildcard for any domain possible, with www.****.*** -> /var/www/****.***/www/ and****.*** -> /var/www/****.***/www/

Answer (score 0):

See the [Name-based Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) documentation for more information about the following directives.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.website.com
ServerAlias website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/website.com/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.website.com/www
</VirtualHost>
```

If you are using [Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) (above is for 2.2), replace `NameVirtualHost *:80` with `Listen 80`

If you need something more dynamic, visit http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html

Comment: Note that NameVirtualHost does nothing in Apache 2.4.

Comment: I'm afraid that it's not that I need. I need to be able to add new websites without changing apache configuration, just create a new folder and it will work. So configuration must be like  a wildcard for any domain possible, with www.****.*** -> /var/www/****.***/www/ and****.*** -> /var/www/****.***/www/